# Proving that a $p$-group operating on a finite set of order not divisible by $p$ has a fixed point.

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^e$ for some prime $p$.  Let $S$ be a set of size not divisible by $p$.  I know that

$|G| = |Stab(s)|\cdot|O_s|$ = (stabilizer of $s$)(orbit of $s$)

So if there is no fixed point then the $|O_s|$ is never $1$, so by the class equation

$|G| = \sum_{orbits} |O_s| = \sum_{orbits} p^{e(s)}$, since $|O_s|$ divides $|G|$.  Since there is no $1$ in the sum, it's divisible by some maximal $p^\ell$.  Factoring out $p^\ell$, then we have $|G|/p^\ell = p^k = 1 + \dots $ *(multiples of $p$)*, which is impossible, since $1$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Am I missing any thing to make this a complete proof?

Comment: Why is there no $1$ in the sum?

Comment: @Lubin OP says "if there is no fixed point then the $|O_s|$ is never $1$," which is correct.

Comment: @anon, yes, right, of course. I was transfixed by the easiness of a direct proof rather than one by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two criticisms:

1. It is perfectly possible to divide $|G|$ by $p^\ell$ and get $$|G|/p^\ell=\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{{\rm multiple~of~}p}+({\rm multiples~of~}p).$$
2. In any case the class equation yields the size of $S$ not of $G$ so the above is moot. You could still divide $|S|$ by the maximal $p^\ell$ and get multiple $1$s in the resulting sum. The point is not the number of $1$s on the RHS after dividing by the $p^\ell$, but the fact that $p$ divides $|S|$ at all!

The idea here is: *no fixed point* $\implies |S|=\sum ({\rm multiples~of~}p)\implies 0\not\equiv |S|\equiv0$ mod $p$, absurd.

Comment: That makes sense.  So the proof is rather simple.

Comment: In fact much more can be said: the number of fixed points in the set is congruent with the number of elements in the set modulo $\;p\;$ ...:)