# Number of fixed points of a $p$-group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

If a $p$-group $G$ acts on a finite set $S$, show that the number of fixed points of the action is congruent mod $p$ to the cardinality $|S|$ of the set $S$.

Let $F$ be the collection of fixed points. Since I know that the cardinality of the orbit $O$ for any given $s \in S$ equals $|G: Stab_{G}(s)|$, I can say all the fixed points, by definition, have orbits of cardinality 1. Because of the order of $G$, each non-trivial index must be a power of $p$. So, summing up cardinalities of the non-trivial orbits will give me some multiple of $p$. Is this correct or only partway there?

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I wasn't sure what I was getting when I added all those orbits up, but I should be getting precisely the non-fixed elements by the very definition of an orbit.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369999/the-fixed-point-theorem-in-artins-book,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201297/if-a-p-group-acts-on-another-p-group-by-automorphisms-there-is-a-nontrivial

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506505/proving-that-a-p-group-operating-on-a-finite-set-of-order-not-divisible-by-p

Answer (score 1):

To remove this from the unanswered pool, the confirmation by anon in the comments seems to have resolved the question. So we add this as an answer.

"Yep, that's the idea."